# Cherry pick a list of patch in review Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have a list of patch in review on Gerrit (31 patches that follow each other), and would like to know how to pull them all at once on my local git.

I know it is possible to download a patch though the graphical interface:

```
Checkout: git fetch <url> refs/changes/78/141978/9 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
Cherry Pick: git fetch <url> refs/changes/78/141978/9 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
Format Patch: git fetch <url> refs/changes/78/141978/9 && git format-patch -1 --stdout FETCH_HEAD
Pull git pull <url> refs/changes/78/141978/9
Patch-File 376aeb6.diff.base64  |   376aeb6.diff.zip
Archive tgz | tar | tbz2 | txz
```

I usually fetch the patch and cherry pick it using the command:

```
git fetch <url> refs/changes/78/141978/9 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

But I don't want to do this for all the patches I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use git cherry-pick to get a bench of consecutive patches.

```
git fetch <url> refs/changes/78/141978/9 
git cherry-pick <first-patch-sha>^..<last-patch-sha>
```

The fetch command will download the patches from the remote repository and the cherry-pick command will apply the changes from `<first-patch-sha>` included to `<last-patch-sha>` included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST api and a Bash script:

```
changes=$(curl -s --request GET --user USER:PASS "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=owner:self+AND+status:open&o=CURRENT_REVISION" | sed 1d | jq --raw-output ".[].revisions[].ref")

for c in $changes
do
    echo ""
    echo $c
    echo ""

    git fetch URL $c && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
done
```

More info at Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes).